Why do in Asian Power system they use Corrugated screen cables?
I’m an Electrical Engineer currently working in Europe.While browsing photos of work sites in China and other Asian countries, particularly during cable-laying operations, I have noticed the following:
Nearly all the cables seem to have corrugated sheaths or wavy metal screens. Based on my experience, I know that smooth sheath cables generally offer better electrical performance.
Are there specific reasons for the preference for corrugated sheath cables in these regions? Could it be related to mechanical protection, cost, or installation practices?

Could you [edit] into the question some sample photos (with necessary citation / attribution to the source) showing the difference in the techniques?

Do you mean ducting? Corrugated ducts are common. Screens are corrugated for flexibility and to allow reduced bend radius, but you won't see that unless the sheath is stripped:https://www.nexans.com.au/en/products/Medium-Voltage/MV-Triplex/12.7-22kV-25773.html

Yes right, I'm not pointing to corrugated ducts but my question is about the corrugated screen which is inside the cable. I know that the corrugated screen has some advantages like reducing bend radius, but they usually end up with higher cable lying cost. My question is, why do they use this type often in a place where smooth screen cable can be used. (Basically smooth screen is being used everywhere in Europe and it works well! )

Sheathing provides a cable with mechanical protection. This protects the cable from physical damage, caused by abrasion, frictions, and external impact during installation, handling, and use – alongside protection from mechanical impact and crushing forces. Also when buried in the earth the corrugations offer collapse resistance to pressure from outside while allowing the cable to bend and twist .
